# 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'abs'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this dataframe and code.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'userId': [10,20,10,20,10,20,10,20],
                   'movieId': [500,500,800,800,700,700,1100,1100],  
                   'ratings': [4.5,4.5,2.0,2.0,4.0,1.5,3.5,2.5]})
def finding_rating(df):


    r = df.pivot(index="movieId",columns="userId")
    r.columns = ["u1","u2"]                                                                                                

    r["drate"] = r.u1.sub(r.u2).abs()
    v = r.drate.iloc[:-1].mean()-r.drate.iloc[-1].abs()
    print(r,v)

finding_rating(df)
```

I'm trying to take abs() value of `v`but it's giving this error. `'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'abs'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because working with scalars use:

```
v = abs(r.drate.iloc[:-1].mean()-r.drate.iloc[-1])
```

Or

```
v = (r.drate.iloc[:-1].mean()-r.drate.iloc[-1]).__abs__()
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling abs() wrongly.

use as below:

```
    v = abs(r.drate.iloc[:-1].mean()-r.drate.iloc[-1])
```

Comment: This is exactly same as @jezrael's answer.

Comment: Yes, I noticed just now. Missed by 2 mins. Lol